# Why does difference between same dates shows a difference of 1 month in Excel?

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

Please take a look at the figure.

The value in cell A3 is the difference between the values in cell A1 and cell A2.

Please explain why the month value is 01 when it should be zero as the month values are same in A1 and A2.
(The format of all three cells is in date format.)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you have formatted the result just like the input, 'dd-mm-yy'. Therefore, you are telling Excel to work with dates instead of integers.

The 1st date for Excel is `1-1-1900`. This is a date representation of the integer `1`. Therefore, `0` == `0-1-1900`. So formatting this as mm-dd-yy == `00-01-00`

Answer (score 2):

For substracting dates you should look at `DATEDIF` formula: [datedif](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/datedif-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c)

Date in excel is a day number starting from 1900 01 01 (number 1).
Format your cells to general and you will see that you are substracting 45008 from 45008 which is equal to 0. Format 0 as a date and you will get 1900 01 00:

[image]